# Change the height of minipage in the figure environment?

Tags: graphics

How can I change the height of the minipage  in the figure envirment? Since I tried it so `\includegraphics[width=.6, height=0.8\linewidth]{img/moovit_4}` and I got this error 
`! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).` 
How can I put code here? it is not like stackoverflow, I can not see the icon right to the image icon in the header. I used these quotation marks``

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{img/moovit_2}
  \captionof{figure}{A figure}
  \label{fig:test1}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.6, height=.8\linewidth]{img/moovit_4}
  \captionof{figure}{Another figure}
  \label{fig:test2}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: You have to pass a unity to `.6`. For example `.6\linewidth` or `3cm`.

Comment: also don't use both width and height or you will distort the figure, and did you intend ` height=.8\linewidth` ie setting the height of the image based on the available width?

Answer (score 5):

As @sigur has already pointed out in a comment, you need to adjust the way you specify the width of the second image. You may also want to align the minipages in a way that both captions are at the same level; this can be done, e.g., by setting the location specifier `[b]` for the two `minipage` environments.

A separate comment: Since the two `minipage`s occur inside a float of type `figure`, it's not necessary to write `\captionof{figure}{...}`; the simpler `\caption{...}` will do too. Finally, the first `\centering` statement (right after `\begin{figure}[H]`) is redundant since the two `minipage`s occupy the full width of the textblock -- nothing there to center, really.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % omit 'demo' option in real document
\usepackage{caption} 
\usepackage{float}   % for "H" location specifier
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
%%\centering  %% redundant
\begin{minipage}[b]{.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{img/moovit_2}
  \caption{A figure}
  \label{fig:test1}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[b]{.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.6\linewidth, height=.8\linewidth]{img/moovit_4}
  \caption{Another figure}
  \label{fig:test2}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```